# Url.Action not routing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make navigation buttons for an image gallery. When I click next it passes a parameter to indicate which action needs to be performed e.g. Next. Instead I get a 404 error. Here is the code details:

**RouteConfig.cs:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{actionType}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", actionType = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="post-navi">
                <a class="prev" href="@Url.Action("Portfolio", "Gallery", new { actionType = "Prev" })">&lt;</a>
                <a class="next" href="@Url.Action("Portfolio", "Gallery", new { actionType = "Next" })">&gt;</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class GallaryController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Gallary/Portfolio/actionType
    public ActionResult Portfolio(string actionType)
    {
        List<Gallary> gallery = null;

        if (actionType == "Prev")
        {
            gallery = Gallary.getPortfolioPrev();
        }
        else if (actionType == "Next")
        {
            gallery = Gallary.getPortfolioNext();
        }
        else
        {
            gallery = Gallary.getPortfolioGallery();
        }

        return View(gallery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change Gallary to Gallery...
Wrong controller name...

Comment: Thank you. My dumb mistake.